# C# using params and extension methods

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Is the params keyword really not supported within extension methods?

I have found that when I create extension methods with the params keyword, that I get "No overloaded method for X takes 2 arguments".  Intellisense recognizes the extension method and even knows that it needs an object array.

Here's some sample code:

```
public static DalRow EasyRetrieveSingle(this DalRow dalRow, object[] parameters) 
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i += 2)
        dic.Add(parameters[i].ToString(), parameters[i + 1]);

    List<DalRow> list = DalRow.RetrieveByFieldValues(dalRow.Structure, null, dic).Cast<DalRow>().ToList();
    if (list.Count == 0) return null;
    return list[0];
}
```

Here's some sample code that calls it (to no avail)

```
(new X()).EasyRetrieveSingle(1, 2);
```

Comment: Works for me. It looks like you're missing `params` in your code snippet?

Comment: Wow! This has to be the freaking head cold.  My apologies for the question.

Comment: No worries. Please don't change the title, as embarrassed as you feel, it'll help other people googling the same problem

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `params` keyword...

```
public static DalRow EasyRetrieveSingle(this DalRow dalRow, params object[] parameters)
```

Answer (score 9):

You're missing the `params` keyword in your method declaration.

```
public static DalRow EasyRetrieveSingle(
    this DalRow dalRow, params object[] parameters)
                          ↑
```

This compiles and runs perfectly:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void Test(this Program program, params object[] args) { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new Program().Test(1, 5);
    }
}
```